# Xamarin Binding property on viewmodels:viewmodel not recognized

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, data-binding

I walked into an issue where I wanted to use a DataTemplateSelector for a single item. In this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6052#issuecomment-488032370) I came accross an answer that extends a contentview and allows for this to happen. I now use this with two Data Templates. The bindingcontext I pass into these works great. But as soon as I want to use another bindingcontext it just says it can't find it.

My DataTemplate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Universal_ONE.ViewModels">
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AirpointSettingsDataTemplate">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                      x:Name="StackName"
                      Spacing="10">
            <Label Text="TestAirpoint" TextColor="Black" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Roboto"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding U}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Roboto">
                <Label.BindingContext>
                    <viewmodels:AirpointSettingsViewModel/>
                </Label.BindingContext>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
     </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The viewmodel:

```
public class AirpointSettingsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public AirpointSettingsViewModel()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ViewModel Airpoint settings");
    }

    private string u = "sometext";
    public string U
    {
        get => u;
        set 
        {
            u = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(U)));
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

When putting breakpoints in the viewmodel it does also not hit those breakpoints.

I also tested with the viewmodel as a bindingcontext of the stacklayout, but that doesn't do anything either.

The error:

```
[0:] Binding: 'U' property not found on 'Universal_ONE.ViewModels.AirpointSettingsViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'
```

I have also tested with a totally unrelated viewmodel on a random property. It still won't find it then. Thus the problem is not that it can't find the viewmodel or that it is faulty.

Comment: According to your code, you bind one viewmodel for Label BindingContext in DataTemplate, Where do you use this DatTemplate?

Comment: It is used in a contentpage. The datatemplate is loaded via a data template selector which in turn is loaded via code that comes from the github issue I linked. The data template gets a bindingcontext from this selector. Which is also the item from which the template is chosen. However, I don't see this as relevant since I should be able to use any bindingcontext on any element

Comment: I use your DataTemplate in StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemTemplate to test, having no problems, please provide one simple sample that can reproduce your problem at github to test.